# How should I share the key of the AES algorithm in each client?

Tags: passwords, cryptography, password-management, aes

My doubt would be the following:

How should each client know the encryption key? Using the AES algorithm.
(or the best way):

- Save it in a file encrypted by password?
- Save it in a DB?
- Send it over the network via SSL?

PS:

- How often is it advisable to change the password?
- Is it advisable that while the program is running it is saved in a private variable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is called key distribution. Key distribution requires you to use a secure channel. This can be:

- Symmetric using a password (but then you need to distribute the password securely, so it is a bit of a chicken and egg problem).
- A DB is not considered a secure way of sharing keys
- SSL: assymetric encryption is one way of doing it, but in this case you could just implement SSL/TLS on your app in the first place. Similar to HTTPS is used (in fact it uses hybrid encryption to exchange a symmetric key that is then used with AES, or another symmetric cipher, for exchanging the data)
- Another option is to use a hardware token that contains the encryption key (e.g. Yubikey). This can for instance be used to do mutual SSL authentication.

For your second part of your question:

- This is highly debated, in general it depends on the use case of your application and how much data it encrypts. The more data it encrypts, the quicker you would need to rotate it. But this all depends on the algorithm etc. (e.g. AES GCM mode loses protection if more than 64 GB is encrypted on the same key. See NIST SP 800-38D section 5.2.1.1). So there's no single right answer. If you are going for the SSL option, every 365 days is probably your best bet.
- Wether that variable is public or private does not matter. One thing to note is that rather than using String it should be char array (if using a managed language like Java or .NET) to prevent the key from being dumped to a memdump in case your machine crashes. The idea is that you load the key before each encryption/decryption and then overwrite the variable with 0's once you have finished the operation. This will reduce the likelihood of the key leaking.

Using SSL/TLS with certificate pinning in your application would be the easiest as you can actually use a different, mutually agreed symmetric key for each session you set up with your client.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. Regarding what you said about the variable String, does this depend on the language used? Or the operating system?

Comment: Language used, the issue with managed languages as compared to lower level languages is that you cant control the garbage collector. This means that even if you overwrite a string it may still linger in memory.

Comment: I know I ask a little late, but leave this problem for later:
I decided to use (in java) the RSA asymmetric encryption to encrypt the AES key as you mentioned, then each client shares their public key and the AES key is sent encrypted each time a client sends a message to another.
If I generate the key pair for RSA each time the program is started and stored in RAM (as private constants), is it considered to be very insecure ?.